# Failed to upload image file in post man

Tags: node.js, json, postman

//I have already on allow reading files outside working directory in postman and also change my image file path from desktop to the postman user file but it does not work

//answer-->[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ggGp.png)

//error screenshots-->
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDUgO.png)

[cmd prompt error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koCJQ.png)

[postman error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdDvz.png)

```
 const formidable=require("formidable");
    const {errorHandler}=require('../helpers/dbErrorHandler');
    const _=require("lodash");
    const fs=require('fs');
    const Product=require("../models/product");
    
    
    exports.create=(req,res)=>{
     let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();//IncomingForm is a method of Formidable package and form data sent from react/postman
     form.keepExtensions=true;//whatever image type we getting extenion will be there
      form.parse(req,(err,fields,files)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:"image could not be uploaded"
            })
        }
        let product=new Product(fields);//fields-->like name,description etc
        if(files.photo)//for photo & files.photo means user sent photo
        {
            product.photo.data=fs.readFileSync(files.photo.filepath);
            product.photo.contentType=files.photo.mimetype;
        }
        product.save((err,result)=>{
            if(err)
            {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error:errorHandler(err)
                })
            }
            res.json(result);
        })
    })
    };
```

Comment: Can you log the details of the `err` received from ` form.parse` ?

Comment: no i didnot do that

Comment: it shows formidable error

Comment: What does it say, it might contain the information to help us find out what's the issue is

Comment: FormidableError: bad content-type header, no content-type

Comment: i add screenshot in my question, this one-->//error screenshots--> cmd

Comment: Do you set correct `content-type` header when sending request from postman?
Can you show the screenshot of the headers from Postman?

Comment: The `content-type` header should be something like `multipart/form-data`

Comment: i didnot add this header

Comment: thanks at last its works thanks  all problem solved  i add this in my question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up. The solution was to set the `content-type` header in postman request to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: thanks again and check my answer screenshot link in my question

Comment: @hacksrinja333 I see it, good job